# can't install snap ros package

Tags: snappy

I just build and published ros2 packages in snap repo with the hlep of github action without any error. [Here](https://snapcraft.io/turtlebot/listing) is the link just for testing. But now when i install the package 'turtlebot' in my raspberry pi with arm64 architecture and desktop amd64 system. Both is showing same error:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Package 'turtlebot3_navigation2' not found: "package 'turtlebot3_navigation2' not found, searching: ['/snap/turtlebot/5/opt/ros/foxy']"
```

Here is the snapcraft yml file:

```
name: turtlebot
version: '0.1'
summary: ROS2 Turtlebot3
description: |
  This example launches a ROS2 Turtlebo3.

grade: devel
confinement: strict
base: core20

architectures:
  - build-on: amd64
    run-on: [amd64, arm64]

parts:
  turtlebot:
    plugin: colcon
    source: .
    source-subdir: turtlebot3_navigation2, turtlebot3_cartographer
        build-packages: [make, gcc, g++]
        stage-packages: [ros-foxy-ros2launch]

apps:
  turtlebot3-cartographer:
    command: opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer cartographer.launch.py
    plugs: [network, network-bind]
    extensions: [ros2-foxy]
  turtlebot3-navigation2:
    command: opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py
    plugs: [network, network-bind]
    extensions: [ros2-foxy]
```

Comment: What system are you running on the PI? If Raspbian, it is 32-bit.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 server. arm64.